# Does filter surface area affect resistance?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid-filtration

I am in the process of designing the enclosure for a small kiosk like project, and intend on having two fans (Noctua NF-A12x25, chosen for their high runtime rating, quietness, as well as other factors). I want to filter the air to prevent dust accumulation over many years of operation, and have tried searching for a way to choose a filter, but I am too inexperienced in this topic and cant seem to find the right keywords.

What I want to know is, given a filter that filters smaller particles, and thus causes more resistance to the air, can "two" of them be placed in "parallel" to increase airflow? is there a limiting factor, or can we possibly use a small fan with a very large strong filter?

My apologies if my question is too basic or if my tags are wrong

Answer (score 1):

For every doubling of the filter area, the flow resistance is cut in half, and the useful lifetime of the filter is doubled. But  because your kiosk is so small, just go down to your local hardware store and buy a disposable *furnace filter* for a home heating system in the smallest size available.

Those filters come in different filtration particle size ratings. The one you want will be the one that takes out the smallest particles. They cost more but are far more effective.

Install the system and run it for several months, then disassemble and inspect the filter to estimate its useful lifetime.

One additional hint: if possible, get you a leaf blower and take it into the kiosk and open up all the windows and doors, and blow that sucker out to get rid of all the accumulated dust in there before you install the filter system!

Comment: The kiosk is still in the design stage as a whole. but wouldn't a furnace filter require a high static pressure, which a PC fan cannot handle? I don't want micro particle filtration, only to filter dust so that no noticeable dust buildup is possible inside within two years of operation

Comment: you can buy furnace filter material in bulk, which is a very loosely woven batt of glass fibers stuck together with glue, and spray it down with another product called dust eliminator which is a tacky aerosol glue to which large dust particles like lint get stuck. this arrangement will have very little pressure drop, especially if you make it , say 24" x 24".